# Ignore directory with changes to tracked files

Tags: git

I want to ignore a directory with lots of changes to tracked files? I tried

```
d:\git>git update-index --assume-unchanged dir
fatal: Unable to mark file dir

d:\git>git update-index --assume-unchanged dir/*
fatal: Unable to mark file dir/*

d:\git>git update-index --assume-unchanged dir\*
fatal: Unable to mark file dir\*
```

I tried to force `cmd.exe` to expand `dir\*` into `dir\file1`, `dir\file2` without success. I suppose my problem is specific to the poor Windows console. At the end I created a batch file

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged dir\file1
git update-index --assume-unchanged dir\file2
git update-index --assume-unchanged dir\file3
```

Is there a way to give a directory instead of all the filenames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try, in a git-bash session ([available with msysgit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/share/WinGit/Git%20Bash.vbs))

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged -- $(git ls-files 'dir/*')
```

Comment: I have found it at the Explorer right-click menu "Git Bash here".

Answer (score 0):

Since git only tracks content (in other words, files) you will need to ignore each file in the directory.

I haven't tried this, but something like:

```
for f in dir/*; do
    git update-index --assume-unchanged -- $f
done
```

should (in theory) do the trick.